# AS3 / Using different movieClips in one frame

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

For a project I have several movie clips into one frame in those movieClips you will find a button to go to the next movieClip.

All pages (movieClips) overlap each other.

The movie clips in this case are all different pages that I want to connect through a button.

When I click on the button in the movie clip I can not use `gotoAndPlay` because I want everything in the same frame. I think I should use `removeChild` for the other movie clips to remove them and only show the one i need when I press the button?

So is there an alternative for `gotoAndPlay();` or should i just use `removeChild();` if you click the button?

I have little experience with AS3 so I do not know exactly how I should do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can either:

1. set the visibility with .visible = false/true;
2. set their alpha with .alpha = 0 - 1; (if they are interactive, they will stay interactive so careful about that)
3. remove them and add them (as you already proposed)
4. move them off screen (bad solution)

I would probably set their visibility. Or you can do it with removeChild. There is no gotoAndPlay() for this scenario.

Comment: Weird behavior... unnaccepted the accepted answer and removes his comment. Nice.